# jsf el expression to build methodname

Tags: jsf, generics, foreach, el

Is something like that possibile to build the MethodName with a variable value?

```
<c:forEach value="#{db.pojo.classList}" var="v">
   <c:forEach items="#{db.pojo.methodNamesList}" var="o">
     <c:set var="superman" value="#{o}" />
     #{v.[superman]}
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach >
```

... database.entity.list is a List of Generic classes.

```
List<?> list..
```

I can use the generic class if i know the Methodname.

```
 <c:forEach value="#{db.pojo.classList}" var="v">
     #{v.value}
 </c:forEach >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
#{v.[superman]}
```

Punch that period.

```html
#{v[superman]}
```

That `<c:set>` is unnecessary, by the way.

```html
#{v[o]}
```

I would only use more self-documenting variable names though. E.g.

```html
#{bean[property]}
```

```html
#{entity[field]}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)